# Merge executables to avoid multiple UAC

Tags: windows

Is there a program that can merge multiple windows executables into one that can run concurrently or in a sequence.

I realize this sounds like how virus's often work but I have real needs. I am trying to avoid multiple UAC prompts in an installation process that runs up multiple MS hot fixes.

Any other advice on ways to avoid the UAC prompts when multple exe's are to be installed is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an [elevate script](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.06.utilityspotlight.aspx) written by someone at Microsoft that will allow you to run a process that will run elevated.  So create a batch file that calls all of the installers in succession and then launch that batch file with elevate like:

`elevate RunInstallers.cmd`

Answer (score 0):

May I recommend disabling UAC if it gets in your way, especially since it was invented to nag users into pushing app developers to modify their apps so as to not require administrative privileges?

http://www.crn.com/software/207100934

Comment: Unfortunately this is for our users to take home with them. It's meant to fully patch their system be it xp, vista or 7 so it can connect to our Windows Server 2008 Terminal Services. XP is the main one to need patching but the others also need certain bits, I have created the logic as appropriate.

Comment: Why are they needing to patch to connect via RDP? Disable the file-transfer portion of your RDP configuration (assuming your application doesn't use it) and you really won't care too much if their box is pwned or not, since it can't infect your network or server via RDP. Keyloggers might still be an issue, but making sure their box is fully patched won't guarantee they're clean.

Comment: It's not about if they have a virus or not you physically can't connect to Windows Server 2008 TS without patches to XP including a registry edit and for Vista you need SP1 not so concerned about 7. It's to do with TS Gateway and Network Level Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I was reading some workaround on a website and I think you can give it a try. I did not get the trick with the .xls file or something but there is some usefull informations.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprosecurity/thread/6cfaab82-da82-4ff9-aa61-416f6134c34d

> We can create a shortcut for this application with elevated privileges.
>
> 1. Click Start, right click on Computer and choose “Manage”.
> 2. Click “Task Scheduler” on the left panel.
> 3. Click “Create Task” on the right panel.
> 4. Type a name for the task.
> 5. Check “Run with highest privileges”.
> 6. Click Actions tab.
> 7. Click “New…”.
> 8. Browse to the program in the “Program/script” box. Click OK.
> 9. On desktop, right click, choose New and click “Shortcut”.
> 10. In the box type: schtasks.exe /run /tn TaskName where TaskName is the name of task you put in on the basics tab and click next.
> 11. Type a name for the shortcut and click Finish.
>
> Now, you can double click the shortcut to run the program, and the UAC window will not prompt.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't get multiple UAC prompts if the calling process is already elevated.  Have the users run the primary application as administrator.  Then anything it runs should already be running as administrator as well.